# Unable to Delete links from a D3 force directed graph with arrows

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, directed-graph

I am trying to create a graph in which nodes can be dynamically added and deleted. New independent nodes can be created using "Add Node" button and then I can create children of the nodes using right click context menu option "Create a Child" . Nodes can deleted using Delete Node option.

I have a working fiddle here in which the links don't have arrows to represent the direction:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztvcb2a4/

I want exactly the same behavior but with arrows representing the direction from parent node to child node. When I try to modify it by appending arrows, I am following exactly the same logic for enter and exit selections but I keep getting this error on the line with exit.remove(). May be I am missing something here which I am not able to figure out.
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

path variable is defined outside the function update as a global variable.

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path");
```

This is the enter and exit selection code for the links inside the function update():

```
path = path.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; })        
path.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

path.exit.remove();
```

The modified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/427pzrsc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `path.exit().remove();`. You are missing the parenthesis on `exit`.

Comment: I can't believe I was stuck due to such a silly mistake. Thanks a lot.